# Android Studio ApplicationTest

Tags: android, android-studio

I had previously been using InteliJ and now have switched to Android Studio 1.0 RC4 up and I am puzzled because in my app when I go to start an activity that is in com.X.Y.activity, I get an option on my device to "Complete action using"... and one of the options is what I had intended, com.X.Y.activity, but the other option is Y.X.com.ProjectName. I assume this is some new feature in android studio but what needs to be done in order for the activity to just be launched as expected instead of asking me which one it is? I also notice in android studio in the project structure is the package Y.X.com.ProjectName at the same root as the "com" folder.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> "Complete action using"...

is displayed because Android OS found multiple activities able to handle the an Intent and ask you to choose the Activity to use. It has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Without information about the Activity and how you are starting: it is difficult to make something else than a guess... and my guess is that the package-name/applicationId of your app has changed and you have now two instance of your app on your device.

Look into your installed apps and uninstall everything that looks like like your app, then re-run your app from Android Studio.